# HTML/CSS strange border behaviour with colspan

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I'm experiencing a weird behaviour of border-bottom in a table with colspan. Please see the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Cps.png). As you can see, the border-bottom of the last cell is expanding to the whole range of colspan?

I'm using Ionic Framework!

For testing purpose i've only used "style"-attributes:

```html
 <table style="border:1px solid black; width: 300px;">
    <tr style="border:1px solid black">
        <td style="border:1px solid black"></td>
        <td style="border:1px solid black"></td>
        <td style="border-left:2px solid red;border-top:2px solid red; border-bottom:2px solid red; background-color:lightcoral;"></td>
        <td style="border-top:2px solid red; border-bottom:2px solid red; background-color:lightcoral;"></td>
        <td style="border-top:2px solid red; border-bottom:2px solid red; background-color:lightcoral;"></td>
        <td style="border-right:2px solid red; border-top:2px solid red; border-bottom:2px solid red; background-color:lightcoral;"></td>
        <td style="border:1px solid black"></td>
        <td style="border:1px solid black"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border:1px solid black">
        <td colspan="4" style="border:1px solid black; text-align:center">12</td>
        <td colspan="4" style="border:1px solid black; text-align:center">13</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The code provided looks alright. Checked on IE, FF, Opera.

Comment: Thanks, solved it by using <div> with fixed width instead of colspan and <table>.